# GWT IntegerBox wrap and events

Tags: gwt

A subsection of html which gets loaded into a Frame (IframeElement):

```
<tr>
    <td>Desc</td>
    <td><select id="descfont" class="fontname"></select></td>
    <td><input id="descbold" type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input id="descitalic" type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input id="descsize" type="number" class="numberbox"></td>
    <td><canvas id="desccolour" class="colorcanvas"></canvas></td>
</tr>
```

I can wrap select boxes, check boxes, buttons, text boxes and canvases. But I cannot find a way of wrapping the input box with the type as "number".

```
final ListBox dfont = ListBox.wrap(doc.getElementById("descfont"));
final SimpleCheckBox dbold = SimpleCheckBox.wrap(doc.getElementById("descbold"));
final SimpleCheckBox ditalic = SimpleCheckBox.wrap(doc.getElementById("descitalic"));
final Canvas dcanvas = Canvas.wrap((CanvasElement)doc.getElementById("desccolour"));
```

And this or similar terms I've tried don't work:

```
final ValueBox<Object> title_size = IntegerBox.wrap(doc.getElementById("descsize"),
    IntegerRenderer.instance(), IntegerParser.instance());
```

or

```
'something' = ValueBox.wrap(doc.getElementById("descsize"), null, null);
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

As well as that, I can use the onBlur() event on a text box. What events would be required for the IntegerBox?

Many thanks in advance...

EDIT: changed title size to descsize in snippets.

Comment: Isn't it just a typo? You try to wrap element with id `titlesize` but your input with type `number` has id `descsize`

Comment: No, I have have titlesize and descsize id's in the html. Although I did copy and paste the wrong line for the snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After following the error suggestions from Eclipse I finally managed to get it working and without the need for the onBlur event handler.

```
final ValueBox<Integer> title_size = IntegerBox.wrap(doc.getElementById("titlesize"),       
    IntegerRenderer.instance(), IntegerParser.instance());

title_size.setSelectionRange(0, 200); // hoping this works now
title_size.setValue(vscroll.desc_size);

title_size.addChangeHandler(new ChangeHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onChange(ChangeEvent event) {
        log.info("New value: " + title_size.getValue());
    }
});
```

Obviously now all I need is to add the validation code and account for erroneous inputs.